# Use third party Library in wordpress

Tags: functions, library, third-party-applications

1. The **GA third party library** works with php 5.5 and above, i have this.
2. They say to **install this via Composer**, since i am new to php i have no idea where is it located and will this work on WordPress? Please help me here

Here is Github's url of Third party Library >> **https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol**

3. According to the third party GA Library DOcumentation, i need to add this code to composer:

   ```
    {
   "require": {
       "theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol": "^2.0"
    }
   }
   ```
4. After that I need to run this code on Wordpress pages & Posts which is related to library

   ```
       //We've passed the Google client_id in Calendly's placeholder for utm_term. Feel free to pass it differently, this is just an example
       if(property_exists($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking, 'utm_term') && !empty($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking->utm_term)) {
           $strPageViewed = 'calendly_conversion.html'; // We use different page names depending on what type of event was scheduled via Calendly
           sendGoogleAnalyticsPageView($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking->utm_term, $strPageViewed);
       }

       function sendGoogleAnalyticsPageView($strGAClientId, $strURL) {
           require_once '/path_to_composer/composer/vendor/autoload.php'; //loads the PHP library for the "Google Analytics Measurement Protocol”
           $analytics = new TheIconic\Tracking\GoogleAnalytics\Analytics(true); //you may have to adjust this path based on your setup

           $analytics
               ->setProtocolVersion('1')
               ->setTrackingId('YOUR-GA-UA-ID-GOES-HERE')
               ->setClientId($strGAClientId)
               ->setDocumentLocationUrl($strURL);

           $analytics->sendPageview(); //here's where all the effort pays off - this 
           part is simple :)
          }
          ?>
   ```

**Please help me implement this code and run this library on wordpress.**

**Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a library in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305967/run-a-library-in-wordpress)

Comment: @Nimesh - don't ask  the same question multiple times.